# Display image from bytes in Angular

Tags: angular

I recieve a image in bytes and try to display it in Angular.

this.currentMedicine =res

```
      const blob = new Blob([res.medicineImageBytes]);

      const fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onload = (event:any) => {
        const base64Image = event.target.result;
        this.imageSrc =this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(base64Image);
      };

      fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using custom [Pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) for `DomSanitizationService` could resolve your issue and make the code be applicable for multiple elements wherever the `DomSanitization` is needed. Here is an example code:

First import the API:

```
import {Component, Pipe} from '@angular/core'
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Create the custom @Pipe:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'secureUrl'
})

export class Url {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {
        this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
    }
    transform(url) {
        var myUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url).changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity;
        console.log(myUrl);
        return myUrl;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    pipes: [Url],
    template: `
            <div *ngFor="let item of myUrls; let i = index">
                 {{item.url|secureUrl}}
            </div>
          `,
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {
        //Your Code Goes Here
    }
}
```

For your reference:

[What is pipe() function in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030197/what-is-pipe-function-in-angular)

[How to bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl for each element in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671121/how-to-bypasssecuritytrustresourceurl-for-each-element-in-an-array)